# AWS : How do Athena GET requests on S3 work?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

How do Athena GET requests on S3 work? I had the impression that one S3 GET request = getting one single file from a bucket. But that doesn't seem to be the case since a single query that uses 4 files is costing me around 400 GET requests.
What's happening exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run queries against files that are splittable and are large enough Athena will spin up workers that will read partial files. This improves performance because of parallelization. Splittable files are for example Parquet files.

A 100x amplification sounds very high though. I don't know what size Athena aims for when it comes to splits, and I don't know the sizes for your files. There could also be other explanations for the additional GET operations, both inside of Athena and from other sources – how sure are you that these requests are from Athena?

One way you could investigate further is to turn on object level logging in CloudTrail for the bucket. You should be able to see all the request parameters like what byte ranges are read. If you assume a role and pass a unique session name and make only a single query with the credentials you get you should be able to isolate all the S3 operations made by Athena for that query.

Comment: These days I was also trying to understand what S3 requests Athena makes for my queries. Using Request Metrics (S3>your bucket>Metrics>Bucket metrics>Request metrics) turned out to be a very quick and simple way of getting basic insight. It will not let you filter for your specific query, so you need an extra bucket or prefix for your tests.